# Python: Generate Random DNA Sequencing with Known GC Percent

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I am trying to generate 5 random DNA sequences in python. Each sequence is length=10 and has a GC percent = 0.2. My understanding is that the function will generate the first random DNA sequence, then check its GC percent: if it meets the requirement (20%, in this case), it will return the sequence and repeat for other 4 sequences; if not, it will regenerate the sequence until it meets the requirement and move to the next one. But the current problems are: 1) instead of generating 5 sequences, it will only produce 1 sequence as the output; 2) the returned sequence seemed to meet the requirement of 20% GC content, but 8 times out of 10, I am getting nothing as the output. I am new to python, could anyone please help me with this??

My code is:

```
from random import choice


def DNA_length(length):
    DNA = ""
    for count in range(length):
        DNA += choice ("CGTA")
    return DNA

for i in range(5):
    DNA = DNA_length(10)
    if (DNA.count("G")+DNA.count("C"))/(float(len(DNA)))==0.2:
        print(DNA)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't use `for`; then will generate 5 only, whether they "win" or not.  You'll have to do something like `wins = 0` / `while wins < 5:` / ... `if xxxx==0.2:` / `print(DNA)` / `wins += 1`.

Comment: More efficient is to  generate desired number of random GC, that satisfy the desired percent, then fill in the rest with TA, shuffle and terurn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement just passes your DNA sequence if the sequence does not meet your requirement.

```
for i in range(5):
    DNA = DNA_length(10)
    if (DNA.count("G")+DNA.count("C"))/(float(len(DNA)))==0.2:
        print(DNA)
```

Just add this print statement on your code may help your understanding.

```
for i in range(5):
    DNA = DNA_length(10)
    print(DNA) // added statement
    if (DNA.count("G")+DNA.count("C"))/(float(len(DNA)))==0.2:
        print(DNA)
```

**Following way works.**

```
count = 0
while count < 5:
    DNA = DNA_length(10)
    if (DNA.count("G")+DNA.count("C"))/(float(len(DNA)))==0.2:
        count += 1
        print(DNA)
```

Answer (score 2):

you generate 5 sequences, but there is no guarantee that all 5 (or even only one) will meet the criteria. You need to generate sequences till you get 5 that satisfy the criteria for 'GC' and also being unique.

Also more efficient is to generate desired number of random GC, that satisfy the desired percent, then fill in the rest with TA, shuffle and return

```
from random import choice, shuffle

def generate_dna(length, required, percent):
    n = round(percent * length)
    fillin = list(set('GCTA') - set(required))
    dna = [choice(required) for _ in range(n)]
    dna += [choice(fillin) for _ in range(length - n)]
    shuffle(dna)
    return ''.join(dna)

generated = set()
while len(generated) < 5:
    generated.add(generate_dna(10, 'GC', 0.2))
print(generated)
```

sample output:

```
{'AGGAAAAATT', 'TTACAAACTA', 'TCTTAAAGTA', 'TTTATTGGTT', 'ATTGTATTCA'}
```

Note, depending on `length` and `percent`, it is not always possible to get exact number of required GC, so resulting percent may not be exact. This is not the case for 10 and 0.2

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it worked! However, I wasn't looking for answers output a list because I wanted it to be easy copy-paste for excel.

Comment: What's the problem instead of `print(generated)` to do `print('\n'.join(generated))`? or transform the list in the desired print output. Or write directly to excel, or etc.

Comment: buran, it seem that, @Indigo is beginner in using python, I think this the pbm. @Indigo, you can just `for i in range(5):
        res_dna = generate_dna(10, 'GC', 0.2)
        print(res_dna)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) answer:

```py
import random

def random_seq_gc_per(length, gc_perc):
    nb_gc = round(gc_perc*length)
    gc_seq = random.choices("GC", k=nb_gc)
    at_seq = random.choices("AT", k=length-nb_gc)
    dna_seq = gc_seq + at_seq
    random.shuffle(dna_seq)
    res_dna_seq = ''.join(dna_seq)
    return res_dna_seq

for i in range(5):
    seq = random_seq_gc_per(10, 0.2)
    print(seq)
```

The idea is to avoid generating a sequence randomly each time, and then compute the GC content, because it is random, hence we don't know if we will get the desired sequences (with GC content) or not.
For that:

- we begin by generating exactly GC content
- then, we generate the remaining nucleotides AT
- we join them together and we shuffle them.

**Note:** This way we are sure that we get a sequence with GC content. **But**, if you want to use your method that generate only a random sequence and then count the GC content as youd do (for some reason), you can do it, and you have already accepted the answer given by [@JongHyeon Yeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5945712/jonghyeon-yeo)